# Xamarin Android - GetApplication

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to follow along to an example in java and ran into some issues.

I have made my own application subclass which I'm now trying to get a reference to in my baseactivity which all other activities will inherit from.

In java to do this the example does the following in on create:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity : ActionBarActivity
{

    protected MyCustomApplication _application;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        _application = (MyCustomApplication) GetApplication(); 
    }
}
```

The issue is that GetApplication method does not seem to exist so how can i get an reference to the Application, cast it to MyCustomApplication and store it as an instance variable?

Would be so thankful if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
_application = (MyCustomApplication) Application;
```

Note: There are several design principles in Xamarin.Android binding which follow .NET Framework Design Guidelines. One of the principle is that Java methods with `T getFoo()` and `void setFoo(T)` signature are transformed into C# properties.